# How to square the elements in a list of lists using Pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
I/p: l=[[1,2,3],[3,4]]

O/p: [[1,4,9],[9,16]]
```

How can I achieve above using PySpark?

I tried

```
sc.parallelize(l).flatmap(lambda x:x).map(lambda x: x*x).collect ()
```

And got below output

```
[1,4,9,9,16]
```

But I require the output like this

```
O/p: [[1,4,9],[9,16]]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the help pages, take the SO tour, read about how to ask good questions, as well as this question checklist. Lastly please learn how to create a minimal reproducible example to show us, with emphasis on the minimal part

Comment: That is because you're using `flatMap`

Answer (score 3):

you are using `flatMap` and losing information about each set, you should iterate over each list in map

```
>>> rdd.map(lambda x: [i * i for i in x]).collect()
[[1, 4, 9], [9, 16]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create small function that does the square and call it in map

```
def square_it(num):
    return [i*i for i in num]

squares = rdd.map(square_it)
result = squares.collect()
print(result)
```